# Primefaces get selected Row from DataTable (DataStructure ArrayList<ArrayList>)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to use the "multiple select" in a `dataTable`. My data model to fill the `dataTable` is an `ArrayList<ArrayList>`. My problem is that the `selectEvent` variable is consistently `null` and no data is available in the bean.

XHTML:

```
<p:dataTable id="dt_notselectedContent"
   var="notselectedContent"
   value="#{verwaltung.alNotSelectedContent}"
   rows="5"
   rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
   selectionMode="multiple"
   selection="#{bean.alContent}"
   rowKey="#{bean.alNotSelectedContent.get(rowIndex).get(0)}"
   paginator="true"
   paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
   rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10"
   rendered="#{not empty verwaltung.alNotSelectedContentForLinkedList}"
   style="width: auto; height: auto">

   <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{verwaltung_store.onRowSelect(event)}" />
```

Comment: does it work ??

Comment: remove the 'event' from the listener... it is explicitly populated!

Comment: the problem was the rowKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting in dataTable, the attribute `rowKey` is very important, which is used to identify the elemnts of `dataTable`, so `rowKey` should be a unique identifier of a row.

As i can see in you code `rowKey` is realy a mess, you should use a unique identifier for instance the primary key of entity, or any attribute that you defined unique.

You can find this in Primefaces Documentation:

> RowKey should be a unique identifier from your data model and used by
>   datatable to find the selected rows. You can either define this key by
>   using the rowKey attribute or by binding a data model which implements
>   org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel.

Answer (score 0):

rowKey was very false syntax

correct syntax vor rowKey

```
rowKey="#{notselectedContent[0]}"
```

this is the column with my unique primary Key

Comment: Please accept the other answer and add your explicit rowkeyto it as a comment. The other answer so;ved it for you did it? If so, please give that person 'credit'